# Class does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I have a simple loop :

```
   for(Object_ *obj in not.object)
   {
        ......
        Object *objStor = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        .....
    }
```

Interface of 'Object_' Class looks like :

```
@interface Object_ : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * review_id;
.
.
.
.
@end
```

The interface for 'Object' Class (Created by xCode for Core Data Schema) looks like :

```
@interface Object : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rating;
.
.
.
.
@end
```

I am receiving an error :

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x1a1bb48 of class 'Object' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x1a1bb48 of class 'Object' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

The solution online says to declare 'Object' Class as a subclass of NSObject. But I cannot change the inheritance to NSObject as that would lead to the failure of Core Data Model.

I have another line just above it,

```
Subject *subStor = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

which works perfectly fine.
What is causing the error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have a namespace collision. Obj-C has a class called `Object` that will collide with you class `Object`.

Rename your `Object` to something else.

Comment: very poor naming choice indeed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I blindly copied the schema!!

Comment: @Sulthan That's quite interesting.  Do you have any idea what that class is used for?  It has an `isa` pointer, as well as `retain` `release` and `autorelease` methods that I find via reflection, but I can't find the interface declared anywhere.

Comment: @borrrden I am pretty sure it's a deprecated root class. Older than `NSObject`. I think it has been removed from the headers.

Comment: @borrrden `objc/Object.h`

Comment: Thanks, I actually found it on my own haha.  I wonder why is still exists.  The open source files show that it has a private interface of just a handful of methods and an isa pointer, but no public interface (#ifdef'd out)

Comment: @borrrden I suppose it exists for backward compatibility. There is probably still some code around from NeXT days :)